# Converting trig expressions of y to x

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

So, the question I am working on at the moment asks me to find the second derivative of $cosy=1/x$ in terms of $x$. Taking the first derivative ,$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{siny}{x^2}$ and even the second derivative is pretty simple, but what really throws me off is the "in terms of $x$". I know that there's some triangle stuff you're supposed to convert $siny$ to a function of $x$ (I think it's something like $\sqrt{(x^2-1)}/x$, but I don't know how it works and how you get to that answer). Can someone help? (I have a test that may or may not include a question on this tomorrow, and it's the only concept I don't understand.)

Answer (score 1):

$$y=\arccos \left({1 \over x}\right) $$ then use $$\arccos' (t)={-1 \over \sqrt{1-t^2}} $$ and the chain rule.

EDIT:

or try

$x={1\over \cos y}$ and then $ {dx\over dy}= \left ({1\over \cos y} \right)'={\sin y \over \cos^2 y} $ so that ${dy\over dx}={1 \over {dx \over dy}}={\cos ^2y \over siny}={\cos ^2y \over \sqrt{1-\cos ^2y}} ={1/x^2 \over \sqrt{1-1/x^2}} $

and then finding $d^2y \over dx^2$ should not be a problem

Note: The "trick" ${dy\over dx}={1 \over {dx \over dy}}$ is just the derivative of the [inverse function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_functions_and_differentiation)

Comment: I'm actually more concerned about converting $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{siny}{x^2}$ to a function of x, because I have to take the derivative of that to get the second derivative (I know that's how the teacher did it in class, but I happened to phase out at the exact moment he went over this).

Comment: Your answer is exactly what we're supposed to get, but we're supposed to show how we got there and I don't understand that whole part; we're not allowed to use formulas that we have not explicitly learned in class.

Comment: Edited my answer.